# Ruby On Rails : Calling class method from concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, is it possible to call methods from the class that included the concern, in the concern itself ? ie:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  include Encryptable

  def self.encrypted_attributes
     %i[attr_1 attr_2]
  end
end

module Encryptable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    self.encrypted_attributes do |attr|
      define_method("#{attr}=") do |arg|
        # do some stuff
      end

      define_method("#{attr}") do
        # do some stuff
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The issue is, when I try to do that, I get an error like :

`*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method 'encrypted_attributes' for #<Class:0x00005648d71c2430>`

And, when debugging inside the concern, I get this something like this :

```
(byebug) self
Foo (call 'Foo' to establish a connection)
(byebug) self.class
Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby is a scripting language and *the order matters*. The following would do:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  def self.encrypted_attributes
     %i[attr_1 attr_2]
  end

  # OK, now we have self.encrypted_attributes defined
  include Encryptable
end
```

More info: [`ActiveSupport::Concern#included`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).